# Splice within for loop for JSON array

Tags: javascript

I have some data I want to remove from an array using splice.

This is what I'm doing currently.

```
for(var index = 0; index < 15; index++){
  if(data.items[index].id.kind == 'youtube#video'){
    vids[index] = data.items[index].id.videoId;
    console.log(vids[index]);
  }else{
    console.log('no video id');
    vids.splice(index, 1);

  }
}
```

If 'youtube#video' is false then there in no video id.

From this code I get 3 console outputs with 'no video id' but the item of the array remain.
I've tested it outside of the loop manually doing 'vids.splice(2,1);' and they are removed as normal.

Comment: Process your loop in reverse, or compensate the index on removal.

Comment: @Seblor I think you'd just be returning the filtered items, not removing them from the array. Perhaps you meant !== "youtube#video"

Comment: @TommyBs My bad, I understood `vids` as the resulting array

Comment: Still racking my brain on this issue if anyone knows. I tried even 'if(data.items[index].id.videoid != 'undefined'){' with no results

Comment: Appart from the pure JS issues mentioned in previous comments, be sure to add an assignment, like `vids = vids` after your `splice`, for Svelte to "see" the value change (assuming `vids` is used in your markup). See [relevant docs section](https://svelte.dev/docs#2_Assignments_are_reactive).